# FileLoadException when running unit tests in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper

I'm trying to run some unit tests in VS 2005 and keep getting the following error

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly

'Tests.CS.vs2005, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, ref StackCrawlMark stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, ref StackCrawlMark stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, ref StackCrawlMark stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestProvider.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.GetType(IRemoteTaskServer server, RemoteTask fixture, String assemblyLocation, String typeName) 
  in c:\Agent\work\e1023618541fdc56\src\UnitTestProvider.nUnit\src\NUnitTaskRunner.cs: line 539
at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestProvider.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.Start(IRemoteTaskServer server, TaskExecutionNode node, NUnitTestFixtureTask fixture) 
  in c:\Agent\work\e1023618541fdc56\src\UnitTestProvider.nUnit\src\NUnitTaskRunner.cs: line 353
at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestProvider.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.Start(TaskExecutionNode node) 
  in c:\Agent\work\e1023618541fdc56\src\UnitTestProvider.nUnit\src\NUnitTaskRunner.cs: line 26
at JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.CurrentAppDomainHost.Execute(TaskExecutionNode node) 
  in c:\Agent\work\e1023618541fdc56\src\TaskRunnerFramework\src\Impl\CurrentAppDomainHost.cs: line 86
```

The assembly *Tests.CS.vs2005* is the unit test's assembly from which the code is run. This is all set on a local vm while the source code is located on a shared folder from the host. I'm running ReSharper with VS and run the tests through it.

Has anyone encountered this? I'm trying to find the config file that's suppose to contain the reference  *Tests.CS.vs2005, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null*, my guess is this is a reference error related to the path to the host machine. Any thoughts on this are welcomed  :)

Thanks!

Comment: it's saying "that assembly or __one of its dependencies__". Try monitoring what the process does with process monitor, that will tell you more what is missing and why.

Comment: Having a similar problem, did you get this solved Tamar?

Comment: Sorry George, it was from a side project I never had a chance to get back to.. If you find the solution please post it!  :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is the type of error I think it is, it is usually caused by the previously built versions of the assembly files are locked by another process. Try shutting down your other applications and see if it doesn't help. If you do it systematically, you should be able to figure out which one was the culprit.

If that doesn't help, restart Visual Studio.

If that doesn't help either, reboot your computer :)

If that doesn't help either, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: No and no  :(
I made sure with process explorer nothing has a handle on the file and restarted everything. Thanks for your help though!